# XML validation against an XSD fails in Oracle but it gets validated in XMLSpy

Tags: xml, oracle, xsd

XSD is registered in oracle. Using XMLTYPE.schemavalidate to validate an XML against the registered XSD. The API gives an error as "LSX-00295: field element "item" is not a simple type". But the same XML file with the same XSD gets validated fine in Altova XMLSpy.
Somehow oracle is giving the complex type error.

Anonymous script is as below:

```
declare
lxml  XMLTYPE;
l_err varchar2(4000);
l_transformxml CLOB:='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tdvpf:products numproducts="2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.techdata.com/vpf VendorPriceFileTemplate_Volume.xsd" xmlns:tdvpf="http://www.techdata.com/vpf" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <product>
        <base>
            <distributorsku numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </distributorsku>
            <vendor numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </vendor>
            <vendorpartnumber numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </vendorpartnumber>
            <endusertype numitems="1">
                <item index="2">Government</item>
            </endusertype>
            <endusersubtype numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </endusersubtype>
            <vendorproductgroup numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </vendorproductgroup>
            <productname numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </productname>
            <productdescription numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </productdescription>
            <cost numitems="1">
                <item index="2">0.0</item>
            </cost>
            <msrp numitems="1">
                <item index="2">0.0</item>
            </msrp>
            <operatingsystem numitems="1">
                <item index="2">Linux</item>
            </operatingsystem>
            <operatingsystemversion numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </operatingsystemversion>
            <platform numitems="1">
                <item index="2">64 bit</item>
            </platform>
            <version numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </version>
            <edition numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </edition>
            <licensetype numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </licensetype>
            <licenseduration numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </licenseduration>
            <packagetype numitems="1">
                <item index="2">Full package product</item>
            </packagetype>
            <mediatype numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </mediatype>
            <maintenancesupporttype numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </maintenancesupporttype>
            <maintenancesupportduration numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </maintenancesupportduration>
            <licenseprogram numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </licenseprogram>
            <language numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </language>
            <productclass numitems="1">
                <item index="2">Applications</item>
            </productclass>
            <mediapartnumber numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </mediapartnumber>
            <requireditems numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </requireditems>
            <seats-qty numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </seats-qty>
            <users-qty numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </users-qty>
            <appliances-qty numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </appliances-qty>
            <devices-qty numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </devices-qty>
            <migrations-qty numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </migrations-qty>
            <mailboxes-qty numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </mailboxes-qty>
            <gigabytes-qty numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </gigabytes-qty>
            <servers-qty numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </servers-qty>
            <workstations-qty numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </workstations-qty>
            <licenses-qty numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </licenses-qty>
            <processors-qty numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </processors-qty>
            <domains-qty numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </domains-qty>
            <nodes-qty numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </nodes-qty>
        </base>
        <licenseprogram>
            <points numitems="1">
                <item index="2">0.0</item>
            </points>
            <minquantity numitems="1">
                <item index="2">0.0</item>
            </minquantity>
            <maxquantity numitems="1">
                <item index="2">0.0</item>
            </maxquantity>
            <volumelevel numitems="1">
                <item index="2">a</item>
            </volumelevel>
            <groupmethod numitems="1">
                <item index="2">ProgramPool</item>
            </groupmethod>
        </licenseprogram>
    </product>
</tdvpf:products>
';
begin
lxml := XMLTYPE (l_transformxml).createschemabasedxml ('VendorPriceFileTemplate_Volume.xsd');
   XMLTYPE.schemavalidate (lxml);

   IF lxml.isschemavalid () = 1
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('XSD validation success');
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      l_err := SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 4000);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Error: ' || l_err);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the schema defines `item` as an element with a [simpleType](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Simple_Type_Definitions), which means it cannot contain attributes.

```
<item index="2">a</item>
```

Comment: "Two men say they're Jesus -- one of them must be wrong." -- Dire Straits

Comment: Impossible be sure without seeing the schema, but XMLSpy has a bad reputation for validation. See, for instance, questions 3668428 ("XMLSpy is buggy as hell") and 4998063 ("XML Spy's validation is notoriously flaky").